# Can I get JMSXDeliveryCount and JMSDestination using org.springframework.messaging.Message

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-messaging

I am using Spring JMS 4.1.2, and I am using org.springframework.messaging.Message as the input payload in the JMS Listener. I am listening to an Active MQ Queue, and I would like to know if it is possible to obtain the JMSXDeliveryCount and JMSDestination using the org.springframework.messaging.Message, or if I have to use the javax.jms.Message class to accomplish this.

Thanks,

Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delivery count property is mapped by default; I just ran a test...

```
message: GenericMessage [payload=jms test, headers={jms_redelivered=true, JMSXDeliveryCount=2, ...
```

Standard headers are mapped with a `jms_` prefix all; message properties are mapped as-is.

The destination from which the message is received is not currently mapped to the message.

You would need to add a custom `JmsHeaderMapper` - perhaps a subclass of `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper`.

I opened a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3968) to make this standard.

Comment: Hi Gary! - Thanks for the prompt reply! I will try and implement a subclass of the DefaultJmsHeaderMapper. I would like to know how I can integrate it. I will have a look.

Comment: Hi Gary - Looks like it all works out of the box like you mentioned above. I had to ensure that the test that I was running had thrown a runtime exception in order to get the delivery count. Also, the Jms Messaging Template uses the SimpleJmsHeaderMapper instead of the DefaultJmsHeaderMapper (from spring integration). Also, the JMSDestination is defined as jms_destination in the Message instead. Thanks for the info Gary! I am marking this as the correct solution!

Comment: Thanks; yes; I'll still fix the DJHM to map the dest, though.